# ElasticBeanstalk Rails Worker Environment (nginx and puma) receiving HTTP 502 error about upstream response header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-reverse-proxy, puma

We have a ElasticBeanstalk Rails Worker Environment which is using SQS and nginx and Puma 6.1.1 and we're getting some weird HTTP 502 errors regarding an "upstream response header"

nginx/access.log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2023:21:01:50 +0000] "POST /periodic_tasks HTTP/1.1" 502 150 "-" "aws-sqsd/3.0.4" "-"
```

nginx/error.log

```
2023/05/19 21:01:50 [error] 31209#31209: *17307 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "POST /periodic_tasks HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/periodic_tasks", host: "localhost"
```

These errors happened after a deploy where we upgraded Puma from 6.1.1 to 6.2.2 as well as implemented a read/write replica for ActiveRecord on RDS.

The interesting part about this issue is that initially after a new worker comes online it moves along happy as can be processing messages with response that are `200 2` and it will do that for a "while" we're not sure if it's time or load-based but eventually it'll start receiving `502 150` responses from upstream and the messages listed above in the error log.

At this point any input would be helpful, we're trying to find a way to get the log of the response header with the hopes it points us in the direction of what the actual "problem" is.

Other posts have suggested looking at nginx variables around the proxy for things like:

```
large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
fastcgi_buffers 16 32k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
```

None of those changes (including downgrading back to Puma 6.1.1) have seemed to make a difference at all.

**UPDATE**: 2023-05-23 5:52PM Eastern

We found that when we implemented the read/write replica there was a `config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_interslice_session'` which was added. Given that cookies are stored and passed around on the response header this is the only thing that seems plausible as a cause.

We attempted to change config variables for nginx as follows (to no avail):

```
proxy_buffer_size   256k;
proxy_buffers   4 512k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   512k;
```

While we do have a way to "fix" the issues it's a revert and not a way forward. Has anyone gotten around this with nginx and using the Cookie Store?